# what is the best alternative for ix function in pandas 0.20?

Tags: python, pandas

This snippet work on the ix function but it got deprecated what's the best alternative

```
df.ix[n-1,'ATR']=df['TR'][:n-1].mean()
#.ix is deprecated from pandas version- 0.19
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? It's deprecated [_"...in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers."_](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with positions by columns names by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.iloc[n-1,df.columns.get_loc('ATR')]= df.iloc[, :n-1, df.columns.get_loc('TR')].mean()
```